# MySQL insert ignore: is it possible to tell which insert failed?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, create-table

E.g. if I have:

```
insert ignore into users (email)
values ('exists@example.com'), ('doesnt-exist@example.com')
```

If `email` is unique and there's already a row with `exists@example.com`, then only 1 row is inserted. Is it possible to tell which of the 2 rows was inserted?

As far as I know, `insertId` refers to the first row that was inserted, but I can't tell which one it was.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, one option would be to have another column in the table, that keeps track of the last date when each row was updated:

```
create table users (
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    email varchar(50) unique,
    updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp  
);
```

Now, say that the content of the table is:

```
id | email              | updated_at         
-: | :----------------- | :------------------
 1 | exists@example.com | 2020-09-23 00:00:00
```

You run the insert statement, which attempts to insert one duplicate:

```
insert ignore into users (email)
values ('exists@example.com'), ('doesnt-exist@example.com')
```

You can use `updated_at` to identify which row was inserted:

```
id | email                    | updated_at         
-: | :----------------------- | :------------------
 1 | exists@example.com       | 2020-09-23 00:00:00
 2 | doesnt-exist@example.com | 2020-09-23 22:33:42
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80afbdb9b2cc3fa6cf5691c2f96cba0d)**

Answer (score 0):

This answers the opposite problem, which values were *not* inserted.  I'm not sure if that is of interest.

But if so, you can use this trick with `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into users (email)
    values ('exists@example.com'), ('doesnt-exist@example.com')
    on duplicate key update email = (case when @emails := concat_ws(',', @emails, values(email)) then values(email) else values(email) end);
    
select @emails;
```

Here is a db<>fiddle.